# Can the TimedAction library be used to call functions of an object

Tags: arduino-uno, object-oriented

Currently to use TimedAction for a function a program would look like so:

```
#include <TimedAction.h>
void functionX();
TimedAction funtionTimed = TimedAction(1000, functionX);

void setup()
{

}


void loop()
{
functionTimed.check();
}


void functionX()
{
 //run function
}
```

My question is say I have an object class with some functions I would like to use with this TimedAction library. How would this be written?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The TimedAction class doesn't support the function prototype required for your undefined class (it has to match your class, so can't be written).

You have to call a normal function which then calls the class function, or you have to have your class function as `static` so it doesn't include the class in the function prototype.

```
class foo {
    public:
        static void runMe() { 
            // blah blah
        }
};

TimedAction funtionTimed = TimedAction(1000, foo::runMe);
```

However, TimedAction is pretty simplistic and you don't really need it.  You can just write a function to only run every so often:

```
class foo {
    private:
        uint32_t _runMeTimestamp;
    public:
        void runMe() {
            if (millis() - _runMeTimestamp < 1000) return;
            _runMeTimestamp = millis();
            // blah blah
        }
};

foo myFoo;

void loop() {
    myFoo.runMe();
}
```

Those two lines of code, plus a variable to store the timestamp in, are all you need to make a function run at periodic intervals.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had been using it to call a normal function which then calls the class function, was just curious if I could reduce redundancy

Comment: Protip: You can re-write the library to use `std::function` instead of raw function pointers. You can then use lambda expressions or `std::bind` to call into a member function of a particular object. This would be the C++ way to do it.